# Windows running on Apple hardware

Tags: windows, macos, apple

I remember apple disabled the dual boot feature, boot camp to dual boot Windows and macOS on Apple hardware.

What other possibilities exist for dual booting or running Windows on Apple Hardware?

Comment: Your question is only about old Apple systems with Intel CPU, correct?

Comment: Correct, but why restrict it only to Intel CPU Architecture the answer? @Robert

Comment: Because it makes a big difference if you just have to provide some virtual hardware or if you have to translate the code to be executed from x86_64 to arm64. Also the x86 platform is next to it's end.

Comment: Ok, so your suggestion is that only virtualization is an option at this time and age? @Robert I'm asking in the sense of virtualbox / vmware etc